# How to optimize animation in a libgdx game

Tags: java, android, animation, optimization, libgdx

I have an animation consisting of 100 frames, each frame is a separate picture with a resolution of 800x450, and this animation should be played in the background throughout the entire game. How can you optimize this animation if you cannot reduce the number of frames and the resolution of each frame?

Comment: Have you tried  to use Video instead of animation with frame. with gdx-video by example https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-video
I've never use it but that can be a solution

Comment: @Ruokki I'll try, thanks for the advice